# Python dictionary pass argument into func used as value

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a dictionary by passing arguments to a function that is used by a key lets say for example:

```
def myfunc(myval):
    print(myval)


mydict = {'key1':myfunc(a)}

mydict['key1'] = myfunc(2)
```

line 7, in 
    mydict = {'key1':myfunc(a)}
NameError: name 'a' is not defined

how its possible to be made?

Comment: are you looking for [*kwargs*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mydict = {'key1':myfunc}
mydict['key1'](2) # or any other argument
```

So just define the function inside the dictionary

Comment: Thank you! thats the solution for my case!